# Error with NEW. OLD. mysql triggers registration in cms

Tags: mysql, triggers

help please, need **last in table** `fz5_user_map` in `gr_id` **increase the value** every time, after another table `user_desc` change

```
CREATE 
DEFINER = 'root' TRIGGER TEST3.trigger1
AFTER INSERT
ON TEST3.fz5_user_desc
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO `fz5_user_map` Set `NEW.gr_id` = LAST_INSERT_ID (`gr_id`) +1;
```

```
fz5_user_map
----------
id | gr_id
1  |  1
2  |  1
```

cms with NEW. OLD. show error

> Registration failed: Unknown column 'NEW.gr_id' in 'field list'
>   SQL=INSERT INTO `user_desc`

how can this be done without the use of NEW. OLD.?

```
BEGIN UPDATE `fz5_user_map` SET `gr_id` = (`gr_id` + 1);
```

how change only last value in `gr_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NEW references to `TEST3.fz5_user_desc` and you are trying to insert in `fz5_user_map`, so `Set NEW.gr_id = LAST_INSERT_ID (`gr_id`) +1;` will not work. You can not insert into the table the insert trigger acts on (results in an infinite loop).

This should work:

```
INSERT INTO fz5_user_map(gr_id) VALUES(NEW.gr_id+1);
```

Comment: again error Registration failed: Unknown column 'NEW.gr_id' in 'field list' SQL=INSERT INTO user_desc

Comment: how without NEW. OLD. using  IF ELSE find the last value in gr_id and change? or maybe order by?

Comment: Are you running the correct SQL? I tested this answer before posting it, works as a charm. 1 difference: I do not have all your code and your data model.

Comment: cms show error, I can not choose another table to track changes in (only user_desc), only this one have error

Comment: `ORDER BY` to find a key is possible, but slow: The larger the table gets, the longer the `order by` takes. See if you can find the correct code, that will be quicker in the long run.

Comment: but how will it look? it will run only when the registration is not so often

Comment: What happens if more then 1 user registers at once? When using a MAX(gr_id) then only 1 value is inserted in your fz5_user_map table. Is that acceptable?